# Live data returning old values , onChanged is triggering multiple times

Tags: android, dao, android-room, android-livedata, android-database

I am using live data to update some view of the activity. the view contain question numbers both total question number and answered question number
 eg: 2/10 (answered/total)
the questions can be filtered using actors, if no actor is selected then it will list all questions (consider the total questions number as 100) then if I am selecting any actor(like a developer, HR) then the questions total number is reduced to another value something less than 100 (like 20 ) 
the total count is returned using the dao method

```
 @Query("SELECT COUNT(actor) FROM questions WHERE actor IN (:actors)")
    LiveData<Integer> getNumberOfQuestions(String[] actors);
```

here String[] actors is the selected actor list

Using an observer

```
questionsViewModel.getTotalQuestionCount(mCheckedActorList).observe(this, new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable Integer countTotal) {
                if (countTotal != null)
                    mTotalCount = String.valueOf(countTotal);
                if (mAnswerCount != null && mTotalCount != null)
                    mAllQuestionAnswered.setText(mAnswerCount.concat("/").concat(mTotalCount));

            }
        });
```

I am observing the count, but consider the scenario

1. no filter applied (no actor selected,count =100)
2. actor developer is selected (count = 20)

onchanged in the first case returns 100 and in second it returns 100  and 20 
 I only want the current value, ie 20 how can solve this? what am I doing wrong?

[image]

in view model

```
 public LiveData<Integer> getTotalQuestionCount(List<String> actorsList) {
        if (actorsList != null && actorsList.size() > 0) {
            String[] actorArray = new String[actorsList.size()];
            actorArray = actorsList.toArray(actorArray);
            return questionsRepository.getTotalCount(actorArray);

        } else {
            return questionsRepository.getTotalCount();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How is specified `questionsRepository.getTotalCount()` method in dao ? Are you using same method again, when all questions needed ?

Comment: no there another method @Query("SELECT COUNT(actor) FROM questions")
    LiveData<Integer> getNumberOfQuestions();

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know whole scenario but a few things in my mind about this

When you make new request with actor change, you doubling(and possibly more) live requests.

So as a result,

- A live query is for all values
- A live query is values for specified actors
- And possible other live queries

Before making new live request you can **clear the previous one**, or you can use List instead of LiveData.

**Sample usage for clearing the observer of live query**,

Hold the LiveData and Observer

```
Observer<Integer> observerOfLiveQuery = new Observer<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable Integer countTotal) {
        if (countTotal != null)
            mTotalCount = String.valueOf(countTotal);
        if (mAnswerCount != null && mTotalCount != null)
            mAllQuestionAnswered.setText(mAnswerCount.concat("/").concat(mTotalCount));
    }
}

LiveData<Intener> firstLiveQuery = getTotalQuestionCount(...)
firstLiveQuery.observe(this, observerOfLiveQuery)

LiveData<Intener> secondLiveQuery = getTotalQuestionCount(...)
firstLiveQuery.removeObserver(observerOfLiveQuery)
secondLiveQuery.observe(this, observerOfLiveQuery)
```

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: I actually tried something similar to this but this doesn't seem to work                     if (questionsViewModel != null && questionsViewModel.getTotalQuestionCount(mCheckedActorList).hasActiveObservers())
            questionsViewModel.getTotalQuestionCount(mCheckedActorList).removeObservers(this);

Comment: Instead of calling like this `getTotalQuestionCount(...).hasActiveObservers())`, hold the live data in a variable `firstLiveQuery = getTotalQuestionCount(...)`, then use `hasActiveObservers()` via the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just call

```
questionsViewModel.getTotalQuestionCount(mCheckedActorList).setValue(null)
```

before calling view model this will clear the previous value